# Editar un archivo Python de forma simple desde codigo

Tags: python

tengo un script Python que editar cualquier archivo con varias lineas, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
with open(f"{settings_file}","r+") as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(re.sub(r'saludo1 = hola', r'saludo1 = hello', data))
    f.truncate()
```

Lo que yo quiero editar son variables de otro codigo Python que uso como base de datos (tenia un .json, pero, las variables de otro codigo Python son mas faciles de leer en otro archivo python en compracion de un JSON porque se usan menos lineas/caracteres.

Mi problema es que esa forma de editar un archivo Python es muy complicada/muy larga, y mi pregunta es: existe una forma de hacerlo mas simple/rapido?

Porque si quiero editar varias variables tengo que colocar el mismo codigo varias veces. **Se puede hacer una funcion con el codigo de arriba?**

Comment: Probablemente esto sea lo que buscas: https://blog.carreralinux.com.ar/2017/09/archivos-de-configuracion-acceso-desde-python/

Comment: No es lo que busco ya que ese enlace solo muestra como leer datos con el modulo configparser, no muestra como editarlos, leerlos es lo facil.

Comment: Aunque, estuve investigando y aqui muestra una forma de hacerlo: https://www.kite.com/python/examples/4392/configparser-modify-a-value-of-an-option-in-a-configuration-file Mi pregunta es: es la forma mas simple e ideal de hacerlo o hay otra mejor?

Comment: La forma más simple e ideal y mejor de hacerlo es con un JSON, muchas veces al no tener una BD, se utiliza json para guardar datos y es mucho más recomendable, además JSON es un estándar por lo que si haces otra app que requiera de esos datos también será fácil y no te complicaras

Comment: Falsa alarma: veo que SET no edita el archivo, solo lo deja hasta que se cierra el programa.

Comment: Quizas lo mejor si sea JSON, pero, mi pregunta es: como editarlo de forma simple? Es decir, editar el archvio directo, de raiz.

Comment: configparser si tiene métodos para modificar valores. Revisa la documentación completa.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion para editar los valores del archivo JSON facilmente:

**SAMPLE_FILE.JSON**

```json
{"a": {"b": 1, "c": 2}, "d": 3}
```

**Editamos**

```
a_file = open("sample_file.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
a_file.close()
print(json_object)

#OUTPUT {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, 'd': 3}

json_object["d"] = 100

a_file = open("sample_file.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, a_file)
a_file.close()
```

**SAMPLE_FILE.JSON editado**

```json
{"a": {"b": 1, "c": 2}, "d": 100}
```